# How to make lattice follow eye position

Tags: animation, rigging, bones, parent, lattice

so i was using latticed eye that works quite well with tracking etc but i have a problem when i change the head pose the eye will follow the head and the lattice wont like this :

[image]
[image]

i tried parenting the lattice but it messed my eye tracking instead, is there any solution for this?

Blend file : http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=52093

Thankyou in advance

Comment: select the lattice, shift select the armature, switch it to Pose mode, select the head bone, then ctrl P > Bone and it seems to work correctly

Comment: its work really well , thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the lattice, <kbd>shift</kbd> select the armature, switch it to *Pose* mode, select the head bone, then <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> > *Bone* and it seems to work correctly.